# Translating numeric code values in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a JSON / Python-dictionary object with some values in a numeric format, e.g. `{'id': 'xxx-xxx-xxx', 'property_type': 930, ...}`. 
What I wish to do, is when I display the object on my website, I want to translate 930 into what it actually means, e.g. 'Public institutional building'.

As these objects come from an API call, there are quite a lot I need to translate, and it is not necessarily for each individual key-value pair I need to translate something. I guess this is common practice to do when working with APIs, however, I do not seem to be able to guide myself in the right direction of any best-practise. I have lots of ideas on how to solve it, but not in any way that I believe is considered 'best-practice'.

Obviously, I would likely have to build up an additional dictionary that would look something like:

```
{'property_type': {120: 'Private property', 240: 'Vacation property' ...}, 'roof_type': {10: 'xxx', 20: 'xxx'}}
```

But what would then be the most convenient way to thereafter automatically take any given dictionary, loop through the 'translation-dictionary' and if there is a match, then translate the dictionary.

In most cases, the object I'll be working with will be nested, so I also need to check the next level sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This funtion can be used to `Recursively` search through a nested dictionary and return what we find.

```
my_dict = {'property_type': {120: 'Private property', 240: 'Vacation property'}, 'roof_type': {10: 'xxx', 20: 'xxx'}}


def recursive_search(dictionary, item):

    # Recursively check for a key in a dictionary

    if item in dictionary:  # Check if item is in current dict
        return dictionary[item]  # our property value

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):  # Check if we have a nested dict
            result = recursive_search(value, item)  # Check the next level
            if result is not None:  # Make sure we don't return early
                return result


print(recursive_search(my_dict, 120))
```